# How do I insert a blob using PDO in Codeiginter 3.0

Tags: codeigniter, pdo, blob

I am using this code...

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO images (imgname,imgtype,imgwidth,imgheight,imgdata,imgthumb,status) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $width, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $height, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(5, file_get_contents($url), PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$stmt->bindParam(6, file_get_contents($thumburl), PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$stmt->bindParam(7, '0', PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

But I am getting the error:

> Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_pdo_mysql_driver::prepare()

Is there some other way to insert a blob using PDO in CodeIgniter 3.0? Everything else seems to work fine with the database helper.

Comment: The problem (as reported) is that `$this->db` is not an instance of PDO class.

Comment: OK. I understand that. But do you have an answer for the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. As hjpotter92 says, $this->db isn't really a PDO object. But CodeIgniter does pass through functions to PDO if you use the conn_id PDO pointer. I replaced:

```
$this->db->prepare($sql);
```

with

```
$this->db->conn_id->prepare($sql);
```

And everything works fine now.

Comment: It works for me , can you please explain how actually it is working ?